# Getting Array.prototype.slice: 'this' is not a JavaScript object with DevExpress ASPxPopupControl

Tags: javascript, devexpress

I just upgraded to ASP.NET DevExpress 16.2 and suddenly the ASPxPopupControl does not work. The webpage throws an exception.

Here is the code where it bombs:

```
ASPx.GetCanBeActiveElementsInContainer = function(container) {
 var canBeActiveTags = ["INPUT", "A", "UL", "BUTTON", "TEXTAREA", "SELECT", "IFRAME"],
  canBeActiveElements = [];
 Data.ForEach(canBeActiveTags, function(tag) {
  var elements = container.getElementsByTagName(tag);
  canBeActiveElements = canBeActiveElements.concat([].slice.call(elements));
 });
```

It bombs on the `canBeActiveElements = canBeActiveElements.concat([].slice.call(elements));` line.

The error message is:

> Array.prototype.slice: 'this' is not a JavaScript object

Not quite sure why this is happening since it is a 3rd party UI add on component.

What does this exception means or how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `getElementsByTagName(tag)` returns `NodeList` which can be treated as array of elements - they're simply host objects. Note that `Array.prototype.slice` is dependent on implementation, some older browser versions (IE 8 or earlier) [have lack support of applying `slice` for host objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

The workaround for this problem is create a try-catch block to determine if `slice` for host objects applicable, and utilize `Array.prototype.push` method as replacement of `slice.call` method when running in old browsers:

```
ASPx.GetCanBeActiveElementsInContainer = function(container) {
    var canBeActiveTags = ["INPUT", "A", "UL", "BUTTON", "TEXTAREA", "SELECT", "IFRAME"],
    canBeActiveElements = [];
    Data.ForEach(canBeActiveTags, function(tag) {
        var elements = container.getElementsByTagName(tag);
        try {
            // this works if running in IE 9+ or newer browsers
            canBeActiveElements = canBeActiveElements.concat([].slice.call(elements));
        } catch (e) {
            // for IE 8 or older browsers
            // adapted from /a/13317785
            var temp = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                temp.push(elements[i]);
            }
            canBeActiveElements = canBeActiveElements.concat(temp);
        }
    });
}
```

NB: The changes above may work if JS code given above used inside ASPX page (not as part of any built-in JS libraries provided by DevExpress).

Reference:

["Array.prototype.slice: 'this' is not a JavaScript object" error in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317752/array-prototype-slice-this-is-not-a-javascript-object-error-in-ie8)