# How to find errors through Angular compiled files?

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

Is there a way to find the error code line with the next stackstrace? I know the error is by using `slice` in some `undefined` property but the app code is so long that could be anywhere.

[image]

By the way, I am only getting the above error in Internet Explorer. Other browsers works fine.

I hope to have explained my problem well. Thanks in advance.

**Update**

[polyfills.ts](https://gist.github.com/fsousa13slb/0f2c88bb8848eb986ae06956f5595660)

Comment: not sure but you'd probably need to add a `polyfill` for `IE`. Also can you have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13317785/3621001)?

Comment: Please check the polyfills.ts file, whether you have uncommented the related import for the IE browser, especially the array package. Besides, you could also check your code, where using an array or the related methods, then, you could try to set break point to debug it and try to find the which part of code will cause this error.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT Actually It's the polyfills.ts imports code that throws the error. I will update the question with the polyfills.ts file

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT I have also already tried to remove all the slice() method usages from code but the error remains

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Try to uncommented the following reference in the polyfills.ts file:

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
```