# How to add a copy of an Object at the end of an Array?

Tags: javascript

How could I add a copy of the first tag at the end of an Array, since push() ,as I understand can't be used in this situation...

```
<p>A</p>
<p>B</p>
<p>C</p>

<script>
var pArray=document.getElementsByTagName("p");
//now I would like to add pArray[0]
</script>
```

Comment: You may find this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735067/how-to-convert-a-dom-node-list-to-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to actually add a copy of the first `<p>` tag to the DOM (rather than just modify an array), you’ll need to clone the node and insert it after the last node:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
var copy = els[0].cloneNode(true);
var last = els[els.length - 1];

last.parentNode.insertBefore(copy, last.nextSibling);
```

Answer (score 2):

`pArray` isn't actually an array. It's a `NodeList`. To convert it into an array, just call `Array.prototype.slice`:

```
var pArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("p"));
```

Answer (score 2):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/JGPve/)***

Push is not available because pArray is actually a NodeList<sup>[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)</sup>. However, you can add to it without using the array method push by simply assigning to the last index. cloneNode<sup>[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode)</sup>  will copy the first element for you.

```
pArray[pArray.length] = pArray[0].cloneNode();
```