# How to remove all classes except the one you clicked?

Tags: javascript, class, addclass, removeclass, toggleclass

This functions starts when I click on a link. It needs to remove all '.is-active' classes on the elements with the attribute [data-route]. And add the class '.is-active' on the [data-route] element that is connected with the link I clicked on.

```
    toggle: function(section){
        var sections = document.querySelectorAll('[data-route]');
        for (i = 0; i < sections.length; i++){
            document.querySelector('[data-route]').classList.remove('is-active');
        }
        document.querySelector(section).classList.add('is-active');
    }
```

But this doesn't work. It doesn't remove the classes?

See example: http://jordypouw.github.io/myFED2/deeltoets1/index.html

**P.S. it has to be in vanilla JavaScript.**

Comment: you must loop on all `document.querySelector('[data-route]')`... you need to store that in a variable and loop them. Also you must use `querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
toggle: function(section){
    var sections = document.querySelectorAll('[data-route]');
    for (i = 0; i < sections.length; i++){

        sections[i].classList.remove('is-active');

        // querySelectorAll return an array of dom elements, u can access them directly.

    }

    // I suppose in your case that ' section ' variable is the clicked element so :

    section.classList.add('is-active')

   // if not you have to store the dom element from the event, and add the class here.

}
```

Comment: Can't we do this without the loop? like in Jquery we do it.

Comment: @TahirAfridi `document.body.querySelectorAll('[data-route]').forEach(i => i.classList.remove('is-active'))` You still need a loop, but its more neat

Answer (score 2):

you can do this:

```
for (var item of document.querySelectorAll('[data-route]')) {
    item.classList.remove('is-active');
}
```

This is **[ecmascript6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)** so it won't work on old browsers. I like it because it's clean and nice. to get it to work on other browsers you must [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2735133/104380) the nodes collection into a real array, so you could loop it.

Comment: Ah yes.  I think this guy is right.  Forgot that there was a loop being used.

Comment: Cool, is this the short version of Samsy his solution?

Comment: yes, his answer is most straight-forward way of doing this, but not the coolest :)

Answer (score 1):

```
toggle: function(section){
    document.querySelectorAll("[data-route]").forEach( e => {

        e.classList.remove("is-active");
    });
    // querySelectorAll return an array of dom elements, u can access them directly.

    // I suppose in your case that ' section ' variable is the clicked element so :

    document.querySelectorAll("[data-route]").forEach( e => {

        e.classList.add("is-active");
    });

   // if not you have to store the dom element from the event, and add the class here.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up a variable for the clicked item..

```
jQuery('.clicker-item').on("click", function(){

var clicked = jQuery('.clicker-item').not(jQuery(this));

clicked.removeClass("active")
jQuery(this).toggleClass("active")


});
```

Answer (score 0):

I felt, that other answers were not neat enough.

```
toggle: (s) => {

    // Find all other sections and remove the active class:
    document.body.querySelectorAll('[data-route]').forEach(i => i.classList.remove('is-active'))
    
    // Add active to the inputted section:
    s.classList.add('is-active')
}
```

Answer (score -2):

shouldn't it be this:

```
toggle: function(section){
    var sections = document.querySelectorAll('[data-route]');
    for (i = 0; i < sections.length; i++){
        document.querySelector('[data-route]').removeClass('is-active');
    }
    document.querySelector(section).addClass('is-active');
}
```

Edit:  Sorry, I should have said removeClass and addClass

Comment: your answer makes no sense, you are looping `sections` but don't do anything with it inside the loop.

Comment: yeah, see my reply under your answer.  I overlooked that he was doing a loop

Comment: so you can edit your answer or remove it..cause it makes no sense leaving an answer that doesn't work.