# Value of variable changing over time inside function w/o reassignment

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<script>
    document
            .getElementById('country')
            .addEventListener('change', function() {
                'use strict';
                var value1 = this.value;
                console.log(value1);
                var vis = document.querySelectorAll('.input-group-addon'),
                country = document.getElementsByClassName(value1);
                console.log(country.length);
                // Point One
                var i;
                if (vis !== null) {
                    for (i = 0; i < vis.length; i++)
                        vis[i].className = 'input-group-addon inv';
                    console.log(country.length);
                    // Point Two
                }
                if (country !== null) {
                    for (i = 0; i < country.length; i++) {
                        country[i].className = 'input-group-addon';
                        // Point Three
                    }
                }
            });
    </script>
```

This has been bothering me for a while now. I am trying to get the value of a selected value in

```
document.querySelectorAll('.input-group-addon')
```

and find matching class names in

```
document.getElementsByClassName(value1)
```

The nodelist of country is available at Point One and changes to null at Point Two.

Is there a basic logic or syntax error in my code?

Comment: If there was a syntax error, the code would not even execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and changes to null at Point Two

I assume you mean that the list is empty. The variable should not magically become `null`.

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a [**live**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110705/infrastructure.html#live) `HTMLCollection`. Meaning it will always reflect the current state of document. If you change the class name of an element, it will automatically either be added or removed from the collection.

If you don't want that, then either use `querySelectorAll`, which returns a collection that is **not** live, or [convert the collection to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2735067/218196).

Comment: This isn't specified in the w3schools documentation. I'll accept this later.

Comment: That doesn't surprise me. w3school is known for having incomplete or even incorrect information.