# What is the equivalent javascript function for .add() in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example for the given jquery snippet, what should be the equivalent javascript. An equivalent add method in javascript can be helpful.

```
$("h1").add("span").add("h2");
```

As it clearly is mentioned in the jquery docs - `.add()` does not add any DOM element. https://api.jquery.com/add/ So using, `.appendChild()` does not serve the purpose here

Comment: I assume that you are looking for `appendChild` method, please when asking a question first try to search for it's answer for little bit and than post it, beacuse this the answer for this is like on the first page of google.

Comment: Well what `.add()` does is extend the contents of the jQuery object; it does not affect anything else. There really is no equivalent because of that. (Note also that jQuery is itself of course JavaScript code.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a div element inside a div element in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622465/creating-a-div-element-inside-a-div-element-in-javascript) (in a way....)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I disagree. .add() doesn't add any elements to the DOM

Answer (score 5):

The documentation at https://api.jquery.com/add says

> "Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .add() method constructs a new jQuery object from the union of those
>   elements and the ones passed into the method. ".

This method doesn't perform any DOM operations, it's purely something for use to manipulate a jQuery object. So as far as I can see there would be no direct equivalent - if you don't use jQuery then by definition you can't create or manpiulate a jQuery object.

P.S. You can always examine the jQuery source code for the method to see what it does.

Comment: The closest equivalent I can think of would be to have an array of Element objects which you can `push()` to.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I would think so. I was just looking to see whether a NodeList could be used, but they're read-only.

Comment: There's a nice discussion about merging NodeLists: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552933/concat-two-nodelists You can't but there's alternatives.

Comment: How can you even instantiate a new `NodeList()`?  Seems you cannot use it as a constructor.

Comment: @connexo I wasn't really suggesting to instantiate one, I was thinking of using querySelectorAll (per [charlieftl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52295773/5947043)) but then being able to add more things to it afterwards as freely as you can with jQuery .add(). Since NodeLists are read-only, you can't do the adding to it later part.

Answer (score 3):

That would create a collection of all `<h1>`, `<span>` and `<h2>` in page

A collection of those same  elements using vanilla js would be:

```
document.querySelectorAll('h1, span, h2')
```

My guess is you expect `add()` to do something different than this but without more details about your use case this would do what is shown in the question

Comment: I guess that works until you want to add more things to it later (because NodeLists are read-only) - which is what .add() does. But upvoted because I think this approach is worth mentioning if it serves the OP's purpose.

Comment: @ADyson agree but don't see OP storing collection either in order to add to it later

Answer (score 2):

Using the native DOM API only you'd have to do a little more:

```js
let collection = [];

let h1 = document.querySelectorAll("h1")
let span = document.querySelectorAll("span")
let h2 = document.querySelectorAll("h2")

collection.push([...h1]);
collection.push([...span]);
collection.push([...h2]);

console.dir(collection);
```

```html
<h1>Headline 1</h1>

<p>THis will not end up in the collection (except <span>this</span>)</p>

<h2>Headline 2</h2>

<span>This closes it out.</span>
```