# addClass to first child of multiple elements in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have array elements, I would like to apply a function to each element in this array that adds the class `.active` to the first child. Currently I'm getting the error

```
'Uncaught TypeError: projectImage.forEach is not a function'
```

What is the problem with this? Any help pointers be greatly appreciated

```js
var Image = {
    init: function() {
        Image.setupImages();
    },
    setupImages: function() {
        var projectImage = $('.project-img');
        projectImage.forEach(function(project) {
            project.find('.project-thumnbail').eq(0).addClass('active');
        });
    },
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    Image.init();
});
```

```css
.project-thumbnail {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.active {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="project-img">
    <div class="project-thumbnail">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250/000000">
    </div>
    <div class="project-thumbnail">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250/000000">
    </div>
    <div class="project-thumbnail">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250/000000">
    </div>
    <div class="project-thumbnail">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250/000000">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="project-img">
    <div class="project-thumbnail">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250/ffffff/000000">
    </div>
    <div class="project-thumbnail">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250/ffffff/000000">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you forget to add `projectImage.children().forEach()`..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a DOM node list to an array in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735067/how-to-convert-a-dom-node-list-to-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `forEach` with `.each()` like:

```
var projectImage = $('.project-img');
projectImage.each(function() {
    $(this).find('project-thumnbail:eq(0)').addClass('active');
});
```

as `projectImage` is an jQuery object not an JS array and `forEach` is an array method.

Answer (score 3):

As the error is trying to tell you, jQuery doesn't have a `forEach` function.

You probably mean `.each()`.
Also, it passes elements, not jQuery objects.

See the documentation.

Comment: I swear you are one second ahead of me the last couple of days. For posterity the documentation specifically can be found -> http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 0):

```
var projectImage = $('.project-img');
```

gives a `jQuery` object. `forEach()` isn't a function on the `jQuery` object, it's only on vanilla.

Instead of `forEach()`, use `each()`, which is the jQuery equivalent.

```
projectImage.each(element => { console.log('do something'); });
```