# Populate a JS array with all values in a table row

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've hardly used javascript and I'm stuck:

I've got a table with id `JamTable`

I'm trying to write some JS that will get me an array of each `<td>` value for any row clicked on, so that I can present it in a popup, wing it back to the server via POST request using an ajax call and then update the elements on the table so no postback is required - but so far I can't even get an array populated.

I've got:

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Get all table row elements <tr> in table 'JamTable' into var 'tr'
        var tr = $('#JamTable').find('tr');

        // Bind a 'click' event for each of those <tr> row elements
        tr.bind('click', function (e) {
            // so that when a row is clicked:
            
            var r = $(this).closest('tr').row;
            var myArray = new Array(r.cells);

            for (var c = 0, col; col = r.cells[c]; c++) {
                alert(col.text)
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="JamTable">
      <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>JAM</td>
              <td>0.004</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>BOB</td>
              <td>0.24</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>9</td>
              <td>Nasty Simon</td>
              <td>94.3</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Yeah I'm totally lost when it comes to JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using proper [event-delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation) is key to success in such scenarios. Catching "click" events on rows is guaranteed to work, even with dynamically-added rows (which were added to the *DOM* **after** the *event listener* was defined)

### Breakdown (see comments):

```js
const tableElm = document.querySelector('table')

// listen to "click" event anywhere on the <table>
tableElm.addEventListener('click', onTableClick)

function onTableClick(e){
  // event delegation 
  const rowElm = e.target.closest('tr')

  // traverse each child of the row (HTMLCollection). map the text value into an Array
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/34250397/104380
  const values = rowElm ? [...rowElm.children].map(td => td.innerText) : []

  // print result
  console.clear()
  console.log(  values  )
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>JAM</td>
      <td>0.004</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>BOB</td>
      <td>0.24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>Nasty Simon</td>
      <td>94.3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You should probably also have some unique id on the `<tr>` if you are sending data back to the server, it might need to know to which row it belongs to

Comment: I've went for this answer as it most closely reflects my original attempt so is easiest to understand, while optimising performance

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jquery for that.

You may use `querySelectorAll` to get the `tr`s and simply children on the `tr` node to get the `td`s

```js
const trs = [...document.querySelectorAll('tr')]
trs.forEach(tr => tr.addEventListener('click', e => {
  // whenever it is clicked, get its tds
  const values = [...tr.children].map(td => td.innerText)
  console.log('click', values)
}, false))
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>JAM</td>
      <td>0.004</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>BOB</td>
      <td>0.24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>Nasty Simon</td>
      <td>94.3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As @vsync suggested, better to use event delegation in case you have a lot of rows to avoid binding several clicks. This also allows to add more rows later on without to have to bind more click handler

edit2 still thx to @vsync, avoid using `onclick` and prefer `addEventListener` to avoid overriding existing events

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table')
table.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.nodeName !== 'TD') { return }
  const values = [...e.target.parentNode.children].map(c => c.innerText)
  console.log(values)
}, false)
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>JAM</td>
      <td>0.004</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>BOB</td>
      <td>0.24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>Nasty Simon</td>
      <td>94.3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Very good, but not optimal, not using event delegation is never recommended.

Comment: You should also never ever bind events without `addEventListener`, it will override previous event that might have been there.

Comment: Well spotted, I'll have a lot of rows so don't want to bind to all of them if I can just check the click target instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can delegate the event from `tr`. On click of it get the `children`. Using `Array.from` will create an array of `td`. Using `map` to iterate that and get the text from the `td`

```js
$("#JamTable").on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
  let k = Array.from($(this).children()).map((item) => {
    return item.innerHTML;
  })
  console.log(k)

})
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='JamTable'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>JAM</td>
      <td>0.004</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>BOB</td>
      <td>0.24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>Nasty Simon</td>
      <td>94.3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>


</table>
```

Comment: no need for the `return` statement if you are already using *arrow-function*. Also no need to sometimes use `function(e)` and sometimes *arrow-function*

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#JamTable tbody tr').click(function () {
    var arr = [];
    $($(this).children('td')).each(function (index, val) {
        arr.push(val.innerText);
    });
    console.log(arr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="JamTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>JAM</td>
            <td>0.004</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>BOB</td>
            <td>0.24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>Nasty Simon</td>
            <td>94.3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: no need to write `.children('td')` because only `<td>` elements can be a child of rows inside `<tbody>`, so writing `.children()` is suffice, Also, it's best-practice to utilize *event-delegation* method, if possible. See my answer for details