# how to re-write this jquery array to javascript

Tags: javascript, gsap

I am trying to re-write this code in javascript only without the jquery part.

```js
var imgs = $.makeArray($("#images img"));
imgs.reverse();

function crossfade() {
  TweenMax.to(imgs[0], 1, { autoAlpha: 0, scale: 1 });
  TweenMax.to(imgs[1], 1, { autoAlpha: 1, scale: 1.2 });
  imgs.push(imgs.shift());
}

var cycle = setInterval(crossfade, 3000);
```

Most especially the below part.

```js
var imgs = $.makeArray($("#images img"));
imgs.reverse();
```

Comment: Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2735133/10210841). I found this question with just a few minutes of research. Next time, try rewording your question while doing your own searching.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a DOM node list to an array in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735067/how-to-convert-a-dom-node-list-to-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: You should upgrade to [GSAP 3](http://greensock.com/3).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This might help you

`Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#images img')).reverse()`

Answer (score 0):

Get the Images with `document.querySelectorAll`, then put them in an array (as @rojo said in his comment) and reverse the order of that array.

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll("#images img"), //get the images as nodelist
    images = Array.from(images), //transform the nodelist to an array
    images = images.reverse() //reverse the array

// proceed with images...
```