# puppeteer trouble. Or, at least, javascript trouble; you decide, please

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Can someone please explain what might be going wrong here:

```
await page.click('some-selector-that-devtools-confirms-is-definitely-there')
let peeps = await page.evaluate(() =>
    {
        document.querySelector('some-selector-that-devtools-confirms-is-definitely-there')
    }
);
console.log('classes: '+peeps.classList)
```

I've tried page.wait...., to no avail, same error

Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
```

Incidentally, is there a best practice for finding out if an element has a certain css class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here.

1. You don't return `document.querySelector('some-selector-that-devtools-confirms-is-definitely-there')` so the variable `peeps` will be undefined
2. You expect you can return any value with [page.evaluate()](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args). but acutely you can only return a [serializable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description) value, so it is not possible to return an element or `NodeList` back from the page environment using this method.

[image]

---

Example to return `classlist` by `page.evaluate()`.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://google.com", { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });

  const classList = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return [...document.querySelector("div").classList];
  });

  console.log(classList);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Perfect! thanks! what's that ... business about? I am becoming a (from)java convert

Comment: This help me to convert DOM list to array to can access it and use all array methods with it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735067/how-to-convert-a-dom-node-list-to-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 1):

There are two main problems with your code:

- Your `evaluate` method is not returning anything;
- You need to access the `classList` inside the `evaluate` method

Here's an example:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://stackoverflow.com/");

  const classes = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return document.querySelector("body").classList;
  });

  console.log(classes);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

As an alternative approach, you could use `getProperty("className")`:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://stackoverflow.com/");

  const el = await page.$("body");
  const className = await el.getProperty("className");
  const classes = className._remoteObject.value.split(" ");

  console.log(classes);

  await browser.close();
})();
```