# Using `.includes` on HTML Element Attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, attributes, include

I want to get an array of all attributes of an HTML element (including their names and values) whose name matches a string.

```
<div id="myDiv" class="myClass" myPrefix-template="artist-group" myPrefix-records="sculptors" myPrefix-caption="People Who Sculpt"></div>
```

How to get an array of all the attribute-objects who's name starts with `myPrefix-`?

This doesn't work:

```
let myDiv = document.querySelector("#myDiv");
let attribs = myDiv.attributes;
let dataAttribs = attribs.filter(attrib => {
            return attrib.name.includes('myPrefix-');
            });
```

It seems this code should work. It's based on this:
https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/filter-array-of-objects

The following works:

```
const characters = [
  { name: 'MT-caption', value: 'Some People' },
  { name: 'MT-records', value: 'sculptures' },
  { name: 'class', value: 'Deep Space Nine' }
];

tngCharacters = characters.filter(character => {
  return character.name.includes('MT-');
});
```

Comment: hint: all `data-*` attributes are available in `myDiv.dataset` - no need for your filter at all :p

Comment: @JaromandaX And i bet you can tell me why my attempt with `data-` isn't working. https://replit.com/@johnaweiss/element-dataset#script.js

Comment: nope I can't tell you that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great answer was kindly posted by another member, but sadly they deleted their post. Here it is:

**New HTML:**

Custom attribute names must be lower-case "myprefix-etc". `.includes` won't find "myPrefix-etc" as stated in the question. Should be rewritten as:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="myClass" myprefix-template="artist-group" myprefix-records="sculptors" myprefix-caption="People Who Sculpt"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
// get element
const myDiv = document.querySelector("#myDiv");

// convert attributes from NamedNodeMap to array
const attribs = [...myDiv.attributes];

// set search-string
const searchString="myprefix-"

// filter the array where name includes the search string
const foundAttribs = attribs.filter(attrib => {
    return attrib.name.includes(searchString);
});

// print items to console
foundAttribs.forEach((attrib) => console.log(attrib.name))
```

**References**

[How to convert a DOM node list to an array in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735067/how-to-convert-a-dom-node-list-to-an-array-in-javascript)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter